# Synonymize ipkg and opkg, or not?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

There's [ipkg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ipkg) (where development has stalled) and its fork [opkg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/opkg) (a package manager used by eg. OpenWRT, actively maintained). OpenWRT is used in home networking by enthusiasts, which is on-topic here.

Recently, there was a [question requesting being tagged with opkg](https://superuser.com/questions/850140/how-to-properly-check-signature-with-opkg), which I created by tagging it. I'm not sure though, if it would be preferable to synonymize them instead.

Pro:

- low-traffic tags (there are some more not tagged appropriately)
- they are related
- probably a lot of question applies to both of them

Con:

- opkg might have features not available in ipkg or other incompatibilities

What to do about these tags?

Comment: A better option to me might be to tag wiki these appropriately, and mention the stallage and how opkg is still active there.

Comment: This is the kind of opinion I wanted to get. I at least added some tag wiki excerpts, for a more elaborate tag wiki I'm lacking time and interest in those tags.